# How to compare 2 csv file if the word does not exist in file delete row

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have 2 csv file, one file contains a lots of datas, in words, numbers and also symbols, called Control.csv, and another file only contains words, called dictionary.csv. Below are the codes i have tried so far

```
import io
import csv

f1 = io.open('Control.csv', 'r', errors='ignore').readlines()
f2 = io.open('Diseases.csv', 'r', errors='ignore').readlines()
f3 = io.open('Compare.csv', 'w')

c1 = csv.reader(f1)
c2 = csv.reader(f2)
c3 = csv.writer(f3)

dictionary = list(c2)

for Control_row in c1:
    row = 1
    found = False
    for Diseases_row in dictionary:
        Compare_row = Control_row
        if Control_row == Diseases_row:
            Compare_row.append('FOUND in dictionary (row ' + str(row) + ')')
            found = True
            break
        row = row + 1
    if not found:
        Compare_row.append('NOT FOUND in dictionary')
    c3.writerow(Compare_row)
```

I wanted to compare the 2 csv files, if any of the rows in Control.csv contains any words exists in Dictionary.csv, the rows will be transferred to a new file called Compare.csv. Each rows in Control.csv has a lots of words, numbers and symbol

Problem: I kept on getting NOT FOUND in dictionary eventhough there are rows in Control.csv that have the words from Dictionary.csv. And the rows that does not contain any words from Dictionary.csv also got transferred inside Compare.csv

```
Example:

Control.csv
1. The National Nutrition and Physical Activity Guidelines For Childcare Centres  is an action to reduce the rate of obesity among children. The action takes into consideration that preventive measures and the practise of a healthy lifestyle should be instilled earlier from school, towards producing a health literate generation who appreciates good health.

2. In line with further development of the country's tourism industry as a core goal of organising Regatta 2019, the event also attracted the participant of foreign teams.The participation of teams from abroad shows the traditional sports is also capable of uniting the local community and visitors from other countries. The participants took the opportunity to enjoy the excitement and joy of rowing in waters.

Dictionary.csv
obesity
diseases

Compare.csv (should have)
1 The National Nutrition and Physical Activity Guidelines For Childcare Centres  is an action to reduce the rate of obesity among children. The action takes into consideration that preventive measures and the practise of a healthy lifestyle should be instilled earlier from school, towards producing a health literate generation who appreciates good health.
```

Comment: I assume Diseases is Dictionary, right?

Comment: @DaemonPainter yes

Comment: according to your code, this `Control_row == Diseases_row` is never true, as `Control_row` is much longer than `Diseases_row`...